# Display the difference of Excel columns with PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I would like to get the difference in the columns in as a table but I only can do a comparison with two columns and it doesn't display all the columns. I need to see in which column the cell is not present in the first column.

The file:

```
ComputerName  OtherComputerName  OtherComputer  AndAgain

infra-1       infra-852          infra-2        infra-99
infra-98      infra-85           infra-44       infra-23
infra-5       infra-8            infra-1        infra-1
infra-2       infra-55           infra-8        infra-70
infra-62      infra-5            infra-852      infra-5
```

The current result:

```
ComputerName  OtherComputerName  OtherComputer  AndAgain
------------  -----------------  -------------  --------
```

I would like to get this as result in PowerShell:

```
ComputerName  OtherComputerName  OtherComputer  AndAgain
------------  -----------------  -------------  --------
infra-1       infra-852                         infra-99
infra-98      infra-85           infra-44       infra-23
infra-5       infra-8
infra-2       infra-55           infra-8        infra-70
infra-62                         infra-852
```

---

**Edit**

I have some errors too when I run this code.

The script:

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\test1.csv -Delimiter ';'

$ref = @($csv.ComputerName)
foreach ($row in $csv) {
  foreach ($col in 'OtherComputerName', 'OtherComputer', 'AndAgain') {
    if ($ref -contains $row.$col) { $row.$col = '' }
  }
}

$table = @()
$file = Get-Content .\test1.csv
$file = $file -replace("    "," ")
$file = $file -replace("   "," ")
$file = $file -replace("  "," ")
$file = $file -replace(" - "," ")

[string[]]$a = Import-Csv '.\test1.csv' | select -Expand ComputerName
[string[]]$b = Import-Csv '.\test1.csv' | select -Expand OtherComputerName
[string[]]$c = Import-Csv '.\test1.csv' | select -Expand OtherComputer
[string[]]$d = Import-Csv '.\test1.csv' | select -Expand AndAgain

$b | ? {$a -notcontains $_}
$c | ? {$a -notcontains $_}
$d | ? {$a -notcontains $_}

foreach ($line in $file) {
    $lineb = $line -split(" ")

    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member -Name "ComputerName" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $lineb[1]
    $obj | Add-Member -Name "OtherComputerName" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $lineb[1]
    $obj | Add-Member -Name "OtherComputer" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $lineb[2]
    $obj | Add-Member -Name "AndAgain" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $lineb[3]

    $table += $obj
}

$table | ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: _"I need to see in which column the cell is not present in the fisrt column"_ I don't understand what you mean. Can you give us an example output, or some pseudo-code that does what you want? [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How about you remove all the clutter that isn't in my answer?

Comment: It displays nothing anymore

Comment: *\*sigh\** Add a line `$csv` or `$csv | Format-Table -AutoSize` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the values of the first column into an array, compare the values of the other columns against that array, and clear matching fields:

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\test1.csv -Delimiter ';'

$ref = @($csv | Select-Object -Expand ComputerName)
foreach ($row in $csv) {
  foreach ($col in 'OtherComputerName', 'OtherComputer', 'AndAgain') {
    if ($ref -contains $row.$col) { $row.$col = '' }
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I get the values in ?

Comment: If you want the modified values back in a file you need to export `$csv` to a file, obviously.

Comment: Yes, I did that but it displays nothing